# Ruby: How do I retrieve part of a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I want a way to only display a set number of characters from a string/text value.

I want it to work in a way that if `my_string.length > 40` then only get first 40 characters from `my_string`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

simply sub-string your string:

```
mystring[0...40]
```

Comment: This will return 41 characters

Comment: No, I'm using the exclusive range operator: `...` instead of the inclusive one: `..`

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
my_string[0..39]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby lets you slice a string:

```
my_string = my_string[0, 40] if (my_string.length > 40)
```

As Andy H reminded me, this can be shorted to:

```
my_string = my_string[0, 40]
```

Here's an example:

```
str = '1234567890' * 5 #=> "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
str[0, 40] #=> "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
```

Comment: You don't need the `if`, do you? If the string is less than 40 chars long, it'll just return the whole string.

Comment: True. I was just following the OPs question logic and forgot that part.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string.slice!(40..-1)
```

You can check description for slice! [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M001214.html)

Comment: This is a bit harder logic to follow. In a production environment I'd be concerned about it being a maintenance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using the activesupport gem (or if you don't mind adding it as a dependency), then you can also use String#truncate. If your string is longer than the set limit you will see "Your string..."